# logarithmic function .

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logarithms

There is this exercise in my maths book, it's included in the chapter on logarithmic functions .

Consider a function $g(x)$ defined on the interval $\mathbb{R}^+_{\neq 0}$ by the following :

$$g(x)=\frac{x\ln x}{x-1},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^+_{\neq 0}\setminus\{1\},\quad g(1)=1$$

a) Prove that $g$ is differentiable from the right at $1$.

b) Prove that $\ln x+1-x<0$ for all $\mathbb{R}^+_{\neq 0}$.

c) Prove that $g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)g(x)<1$ for all $\mathbb{R}^+_{\neq 0}$.

I did prove the first and the second questions but for the third one I can't seem to solve it no matter what I do .

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) rather than image files for formatting mathematics on this site.

Comment: I am new here , hence I don't know much about this site but I'll consider doing that next time , thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the interval R+*"? And in the question, what does that mysterious sequence of symbols "$x\in\mathbb{R}+*-\{1\}$" mean? I can understand things like $x\in\mathbb{R}$  or $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ or even $x\in\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$, but that...

Comment: I'm guessing the $+$ is supposed to be super-scripted meaning "positive reals", i.e. $\mathbb{R}^{+}\setminus \{1\}$, but I can't figure out what that $*$ is doing in there.

Comment: Yes the + means ''positive reals'' and the * means that '0' is not included in the interval ;

Comment: Are you sure about the third question? $x=1$ gives $[g(1)]^2=1$, which is not less than $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to prove c) when $x>1$; just replace x by 1/x for $0<x<1$. Now $(\sqrt x -1)^{2} > 0$. Using this it follows by direc t calculation that the derivative of the function $\ln x -\sqrt x +x^{-1/2}$ is positive on $[1,\infty)$. Since this function vanishes at $x=1$ we see that $\ln x -\sqrt x +x^{-1/2} <0$ and this is precisely the inequality $g(1/x)g(x)<1$